# Multiple field validation in Firebase Firestore security rules

Tags: firebase, validation, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have written the following security rule for the **GameAdmins** collection of my Firestore database:

```js
    match /GameAdmins/{adminId} {
      function validAdminData() {
        let keys = request.resource.data.keys().toSet();
        let allowedKeys = ['admin', 'superAdmin'].toSet();
        let data = request.resource.data;
        
        return (keys == allowedKeys) && (data.admin is bool) && (data.superAdmin is bool);
      }
      
      allow create, update: if isSuperAdmin() && validAdminData();
      allow delete: if isSuperAdmin();
    }
```

So it allows only two boolean fields **admin** and **superAdmin** while creating or updating a document. This method was easy to write since it has only two fields. It gets difficult when  I want to write the same method for a different collection that has a lot of fields since I would have to write the list of keys and check the type of each field.

I thought of keeping dummy data in the database so that I can get the list of allowed keys from there. But I still have to check each of their types separately.

Is there a better way to check the list of keys and their types with less amount of codes?

Comment: You can try using `hasOnly()` method as demonstrated in this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#combining_required_and_optional_fields)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some functions that are not completely dynamic but work for now.

```js
    function validateType(data, type) {
      return (
        (type == 'string' && data is string) ||
        (type == 'int' && data is int) ||
        (type == 'bool' && data is bool) ||
        (type == 'timestamp' && data is timestamp) ||
        (type == 'list' && data is list)
      );
    }
    
    function validateEachField(data, model) {
      let keys = model.keys();
      let n = keys.size() - 1;
      
      return (
        (n <= 0 || validateType(data[keys[0]], model[keys[0]])) &&
        (n <= 1 || validateType(data[keys[1]], model[keys[1]])) &&
        (n <= 2 || validateType(data[keys[2]], model[keys[2]])) &&
        (n <= 3 || validateType(data[keys[3]], model[keys[3]])) &&
        (n <= 4 || validateType(data[keys[4]], model[keys[4]])) &&
        (n <= 5 || validateType(data[keys[5]], model[keys[5]])) &&
        (n <= 6 || validateType(data[keys[6]], model[keys[6]])) &&
        (n <= 7 || validateType(data[keys[7]], model[keys[7]])) &&
        (n <= 8 || validateType(data[keys[8]], model[keys[8]])) &&
        (n <= 9 || validateType(data[keys[9]], model[keys[9]]))
      );
    }
    
    function validateData(collection) {
      let model = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/DataModels/$(collection)/$(collection)).data;
      let keys = request.resource.data.keys().toSet();
      let allowedKeys = model.keys().toSet();
      return keys == allowedKeys && validateEachField(request.resource.data, model);
    }
```

The only problem seems to be I might have to add more lines in the **validateEachField** function when the number of fields increases and add support for more types in the **validateType** function in the future.